# Display text in the comboboxes followed by array of day, month, and year

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to create a day, month and year. There are 3 `comboboxes` in the form and those 3 `comboboxes` divided as follows: day, month, and year. However, I want to add the text into the first list of `comboboxes` followed by (or before) array of day, month, and year. So, the text will appear as `index 0`. But when I added the text to the `comboboxes`, the first combobox which is the day and can select the list from the first comobox, but where as the rest cannot select the list.

How can I fix this?

Here is where I added the text into the `comboboxes`:

```
private void SetValues()
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);

        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Date");

        this.comboBox2.Items.Add("Month");

        this.comboBox3.Items.Add("Year");

        for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox2.Items.Add(info.GetMonthName(i));
        }

        for (int i = 1980; i < DateTime.Now.Year + 1; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        SetCalendarIndex();
    }
```

Here is the full code:

```
public partial class AgeConfirmation : Form
{
    public AgeConfirmation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.comboBox1.Leave += new EventHandler(CheckPossibleCalendar);

        this.comboBox2.Leave += new EventHandler(CheckPossibleCalendar);

        this.comboBox3.Leave += new EventHandler(CheckPossibleCalendar);
    }

    private void AgeConfirmation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SystemManager.SetFullScreen(this);

        SetProperties();

        SetValues();
    }

    private void SetProperties()
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new Size(SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width, SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height);

        this.label1.Text = "Date of Birth:";

        this.label1.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) - 75, (SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2) - 100);

        this.label1.Parent = this.pictureBox1;

        this.comboBox1.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) - 175, (SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2) - 50);

        this.comboBox2.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) - 50, (SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2) - 50);

        this.comboBox3.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) + 75, (SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2) - 50);

        this.button1.Parent = this.pictureBox1;

        this.button1.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) - 40, SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2);
    }

    private void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) || this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) || this.comboBox3.SelectedIndex.Equals(0))
        {
            SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("Date, Month, and Year required, please fill them!", "Information", 1);
        }

        else
        {
            int visitorAge = this.comboBox3.SelectedIndex - DateTime.Now.Year;

            SystemManager.AddAge(visitorAge, Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
        }
    }

    private void CheckPossibleCalendar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(this.comboBox3.Text), this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1);

        if (day <= this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("You have entered wrong Date, Month, or Year!", "Warning", 2);

            SetCalendarIndex();
        }
    }

    private void SetValues()
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);

        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Date");

        this.comboBox2.Items.Add("Month");

        this.comboBox3.Items.Add("Year");

        for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox2.Items.Add(info.GetMonthName(i));
        }

        for (int i = 1980; i < DateTime.Now.Year + 1; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        SetCalendarIndex();
    }

    private void SetCalendarIndex()
    {
        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;

        this.comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

**EDITED:**

[image]

As you can see from the image above, the first combobox can be selected, where as the rest cannot. When I run the program, it detect the first selected combobox. Let's say I select the first combobox, by the time I select the first combobox, the rest of it (second and third combobox) cannot be selected anymore until restart the program.

This happens because I added the code:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Date");

this.comboBox2.Items.Add("Month");

this.comboBox3.Items.Add("Year");
```

By the time I am not added the above code, it is working. But the first selected value of comboboxes will be numbers, texts, and numbers. I want the first selected value of comboboxes will be as the code above, but once I added the code above. The problem as I described from the below of the image above is occurs.

Comment: from what i mean on `where as the rest cannot select the list` is the rest of the `comboboxes` (month and year comboboxes) are not disabled, just I cannot select the values from those two `comboboxes`, but the first `combobox` which is the day, I can select the value from it. So like those two `comboboxes` are not `comboboxes` anymore that I can select (it is like without the dropdownlist)

Comment: oh, I forgot to add that. Thank you for mention it @GrantWinney

Comment: when I run the program and select one of three `comboboxes` in the form, the rest of the `comboboxes` cannot be selected (it is like without the dropdownlist), only the selected `combobox` will only have the dropdownlist

Comment: No, I mean I want those three comboboxes can be selected from dropdownlist items that already registered. Please see the image from the question above as I have updated the question (import image) to the question @GrantWinney.

Answer (score -1):

**Change your code to below and give a test.**

```
 public partial class AgeConfirmation : Form
    {
        public AgeConfirmation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void AgeConfirmation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SystemManager.SetFullScreen(this);

            SetProperties();

            SetValues();
        }

        private void SetProperties()
        {
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width, SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height);

            label1.Text = "Date of Birth:";

            label1.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) - 75, (SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2) - 100);

            label1.Parent = pictureBox1;

            comboBox1.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) - 175, (SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2) - 50);

            comboBox2.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) - 50, (SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2) - 50);

            comboBox3.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) + 75, (SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2) - 50);

            button1.Parent = pictureBox1;

            button1.Location = new Point((SystemManager._workingRectangle.Width / 2) - 40, SystemManager._workingRectangle.Height / 2);
        }

        private void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) || comboBox2.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) || comboBox3.SelectedIndex.Equals(0))
            {
                SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("Date, Month, and Year required, please fill them!", "Information", 1);
            }

            else
            {
                int visitorAge = comboBox3.SelectedIndex - DateTime.Now.Year;

                SystemManager.AddAge(visitorAge, Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }

        private void CheckPossibleCalendar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text), comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1);

            if (day <= comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("You have entered wrong Date, Month, or Year!", "Warning", 2);

                SetCalendarIndex();
            }
        }

        private void SetValues()
        {
            DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);

            comboBox1.Items.Add("Date");

            comboBox2.Items.Add("Month");

            comboBox3.Items.Add("Year");

            for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(info.GetMonthName(i));
            }

            for (int i = 1980; i < DateTime.Now.Year + 1; i++)
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            SetCalendarIndex();
        }

        private void SetCalendarIndex()
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;

            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

I have tested below code and worked fine.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestingDevExpress
{
    public partial class Form01 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public Form01()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void SetProperties()
        {

            label1.Text = "Date of Birth:";

            label1.Parent = pictureBox1;

            button1.Parent = pictureBox1;

        }

        private void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) || comboBox2.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) || comboBox3.SelectedIndex.Equals(0))
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Date, Month, and Year required, please fill them!", "Information");
            }

            else
            {
                int visitorAge = comboBox3.SelectedIndex - DateTime.Now.Year;

                MessageBox.Show(visitorAge + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }

        private void CheckPossibleCalendar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text), comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1);

            if (day <= comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have entered wrong Date, Month, or Year!", "Warning");

                SetCalendarIndex();
            }
        }

        private void SetValues()
        {
            DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);

            comboBox1.Items.Add("Date");

            comboBox2.Items.Add("Month");

            comboBox3.Items.Add("Year");

            for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(info.GetMonthName(i));
            }

            for (int i = 1980; i < DateTime.Now.Year + 1; i++)
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            SetCalendarIndex();
        }

        private void SetCalendarIndex()
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;

            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void Form01_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetProperties();

            SetValues();
        }
    }
}
```